# Add json config file to Azure function for local development

Tags: json, azure, azure-functions

I have multiple ASP.NET Core Web apps that share a common **appsettings.Common.json** configuration file that is imported at program start like this:

```
            configurationBuilder.AddJsonFile(path: $"appsettings.Common.json");
```

I would like to use the same **appsettings.Common.json** in an Azure function that I am developing locally, but this seems impossible. The Azure functions use the local.settings.json for the configuration and it seems to be hard-coded.

To me it makes no sense that I cannot import any json config file in the Azure app like I am able to do in Azure functions.

One possibility is that I move all the content of the **appsettings.Common.json** to the **local.settings.json** and import it in the same manner in the Web Apps.

Do you know any other way I could import the existing **appsettings.Common.json** in the Azure function?

Comment: But even the solution with moving the appsettings.Common.json to local.settings.json is not ideal, as I would have some settings in the Web Apps that are specific only to the Azure function. No idea why Microsoft didn't use the same approach in functions as in Web apps...

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible today. I've filed an issue to track it: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/2730